# I want to make each url in a list a string

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, scrapy

I have 35000 urls and I can't individually add "" (to each url) and add , at the end of each one, is there any shortcut key in vscode that helps me select all urls in block of code inside the list and then string, unstring the urls like we can comment uncomment

This is how I want 35000 urls to look like:

```
start_urls=[
        'https://dawaai.pk/all-medicines/a',
        'https://dawaai.pk/all-medicines/b',
        'https://dawaai.pk/all-medicines/c',
        'https://dawaai.pk/all-medicines/d',
        'https://dawaai.pk/all-medicines/e',
        'https://dawaai.pk/all-medicines/f',
        'https://dawaai.pk/all-medicines/g',
        'https://dawaai.pk/all-medicines/h',
        'https://dawaai.pk/all-medicines/i',
        'https://dawaai.pk/all-medicines/j',
        'https://dawaai.pk/all-medicines/k',
        'https://dawaai.pk/all-medicines/l',
        'https://dawaai.pk/all-medicines/m',
        'https://dawaai.pk/all-medicines/n',
        'https://dawaai.pk/all-medicines/o',
        'https://dawaai.pk/all-medicines/p',
        'https://dawaai.pk/all-medicines/q',
        'https://dawaai.pk/all-medicines/r',
        'https://dawaai.pk/all-medicines/s',
        'https://dawaai.pk/all-medicines/t',
        'https://dawaai.pk/all-medicines/u',
        'https://dawaai.pk/all-medicines/v',
        'https://dawaai.pk/all-medicines/w',
        'https://dawaai.pk/all-medicines/x',
        'https://dawaai.pk/all-medicines/y',
        'https://dawaai.pk/all-medicines/z',
        # 'https://dawaai.pk/all-medicines/',

        ]
```

This is how they the current code base looks like for the scraper:

```
import scrapy

class DawaaiSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name='dawaai'
 start_urls=[ 
https://dawaai.pk/medicine/vitrum-1-38514.html
https://dawaai.pk/medicine/ventek-38552.html
https://dawaai.pk/medicine/valid-1-41158.html
https://dawaai.pk/medicine/verger-2-38699.html
https://dawaai.pk/medicine/valvin-1-38910.html
https://dawaai.pk/medicine/verger-5-38953.html
https://dawaai.pk/medicine/vexnil-8-39028.html
https://dawaai.pk/medicine/virocil-41083.html
https://dawaai.pk/medicine/voltral-emulgel-2-39942.html
https://dawaai.pk/medicine/vasocord-40099.html
https://dawaai.pk/medicine/vasocord-1-40100.html
https://dawaai.pk/medicine/Zestril-Tablet10-55.html
https://dawaai.pk/medicine/Zestril-Tablet20-56.html
https://dawaai.pk/medicine/zultra-1-12104.html
https://dawaai.pk/medicine/Zofrantab-Tablet8-128.html
https://dawaai.pk/medicine/Zeegapcap-Capsule50-176.html
https://dawaai.pk/medicine/Zeegapcap-Capsule75-177.html
https://dawaai.pk/medicine/Zeegapcap-Capsule150-178.html
https://dawaai.pk/medicine/zopent-40mg-590.html
https://dawaai.pk/medicine/zopent-40mg-591.html
https://dawaai.pk/medicine/zoloft-50mg-592.html
https://dawaai.pk/medicine/zocor-10mg-593.html
https://dawaai.pk/medicine/zocor-10mg-594.html

]

def parse(self,response):
        for medicine in response.css('div.card-body'):
                yield{
                'name': medicine.css('a::text').get(),
                'price_now': medicine.css('h4::text').get().replace('Rs ','')  }
```

The thing is that`start_urls` will start getting scraped when all urls are a string and there's a comma in between

Comment: why not consider any programming language?

Comment: Can you share the code you are using and what you already tried?

Comment: relatively new to stack overflow unfortunately how can i share complete code in comments?

Comment: @RanaShaharyar you can edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 Ways to do this :-

1. Use Regex in VSCode (I am not a regex pro)
2. put urls in a text file and Have a python script iterate over them, adding `"` to start & end of line & a `,` to end of each line.
3. **Using Multiselect :-**

go to top left of URLs, hold `Alt+Shift` and drag till bottom right of URLs, this will give you multiple cursors and you can edit all lines at once.

[image]

Then press Left arrow key to bring all cursors to left side, then type `'`

[image]

Now select all urls again, this time press Right arrow key to bring all cursors to end of each line, then type `',`

[image]

Done !

Comment: this is how the urls actually look like there are now quotes to begin with in the original file, i shared that could because i wanted my code to look like that  ` https://dawaai.pk/medicine/biolan-gel-939.html
https://dawaai.pk/medicine/bosmon-625mg-1048.html
https://dawaai.pk/medicine/bon-one-05mcg-1108.html
https://dawaai.pk/medicine/bactroban-cream-1282.html
https://dawaai.pk/medicine/blephamide-sop-opthalmic-ointment-1412.html
https://dawaai.pk/medicine/betaderm-nm-cream-1488.html`

Comment: i dont understand what you want, edit the question and provide both original format and the format you want.